# Listview double click with object as placement target

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

The following Xaml code allows me to use a context menu in a listview and send the row details as an object to the view model:

```
  <ListView.ContextMenu>
<ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Link This Operation"
                          Command="{Binding SelectedOperation}"
                          CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem}"/>
            </ContextMenu>
  </ListView.ContextMenu>-->
```

However i want to do the same thing through a double mouse click.  I have tried all sorts.  Including this:

```
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                      <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectedItem}"
                                       CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=PlacementTarget.SelectedItem}"/>

            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

This works but the object is always null.

Any ideas?

Comment: Where have you put the trigger?

Comment: The trigger is inside the Listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
<i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
<i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectedOperation}"
       CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=SelectedItem}"/>

</i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm afraid the object is still null.  It's very odd

Comment: No.  It successfully reaches the void in the View Model.  But the object in the signature is null.  It should be the object from the selected row in the listview

Comment: Can you post your SelectedOperation in viewmodel?

Comment: Sorry for the typo, above.

Comment: It works when i do it from contextmenu.  Just not from the behaviour i have added to enable it to be prompted by double mouse click

Comment: You can try also {RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}

Comment: This is when I get the message: "RelativeSource is not in FindAncestor mode"

Comment: I've got it.  Thank you so much for your help.